# How to add the result variable of form submission to mapping?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I have this form in a jsp file where I dynamically populate a dropdown from a list. It works fine. This is the home jsp at core address "/" and it sends data to "/spravochnik/list".

```
<form action="/spravochnik/list" method="post">
  <select name="tableName">
    <c:forEach var="dropDown" items="${dropDown}">
      <c:forEach var="valuesInRows" items="${dropDown.valuesInRows}">
        <c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}" varStatus="loop">                                        
          <c:if test="${loop.index %2 != 0}">
            <option><c:out value="${valuesInRow}"></c:out></option>
          </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
      </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Now I have a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/spravochnik/list", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public String getSpravochniks(Model m, @RequestParam("tableName") String tableName) {
        Integer idPrepend = spravochnikService.getIdAtSpravName(tableName);
        List<Spravochnik> spravList = spravochnikService.findAll(tableName);
        m.addAttribute("spravList", spravList);
        m.addAttribute("tableName", tableName);
        m.addAttribute("idPrepend", idPrepend);
        return "home";
    }
```

It also works fine, and the resulting table (what I got from findAll) is shown with address /spravochnik/list. **Question:** How can I show it with address depending on what variable "tableName" i sent from the home.jsp? For example, if in the dropdown I select "employees" and pass it with the form under the name "tableName", I want the result to be shown under /spravochnik/list/employees and if I choose "vehicles" it should be "/spravochnik/list/vehicles"?

**What I tried**
-Adding variable to action
 and in controller @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{tableName}" and tableName as @PathVariable. Actual Result: Not Found.
-The same with @RequestParam instead of Path Variable. Actual result: Not Found.

Comment: What about `/spravochnik/list?type=vehicles`?

Comment: It would have been a good solution, but it is one of the rules of my assignment that I should do it this way and no other...

Comment: Dynamic url mapping with controller is not possible in spring. can we use apache redirect  /spravochnik/list/vehicles to  /spravochnik/list?type=vehicles?

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that!